# webdev serve missing output for .js.map files

Tags: dart, angular-dart

When running `webdev serve` and attempting to debug an error. I do not see any dart source code or `.js.map` files in order to debug it.

What could be wrong? This is a fresh angulardart project using the latest Dart 2, and `webdev 0.2.4`

Comment: Do you have any `build.yaml` or `build.xxx.yaml` file that disables source maps? Do you have source maps enabled in the Chrome devtools settings?

Comment: I do have source maps enabled. I do not have a `build.yaml` file @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's way too hard to do this now. I just opened [an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/1779) on it. In the meantime, try this in `build.yaml`:

```
global_options:
  build_web_compilers|dart_source_cleanup:
    release_options:
      enabled: false
  build_web_compilers|dart2js_archive_extractor:
    release_options:
      filter_outputs: false
```